# Can I specify the jackson @JsonView to use for method result transformation in RestEasy?

Tags: serialization, jackson, resteasy, wildfly

I'm working with a serialization model based on `@JsonView`. I normally configure jackson with a `ContextResolver` like this:

```
@Override
public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
    // enable a view by default, else Views are not processed
    Class view = Object.class;
    if (aClass.getPackage().getName().startsWith("my.company.entity")) {
        view = getViewNameForClass(aClass);
    }
    objectMapper.setSerializationConfig(
         objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(view));
    return objectMapper;
}
```

This works fine if I serialize single entities. However, for certain use cases I want to serialize lists of my entities using the same view as for single entities. In this case, `aClass` is `ArrayList`, so the usual logic doesn't help much.

So I'm looking for a way to tell Jackson which view to use. Ideally, I'd write:

```
@GET @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
@JsonView(JSONEntity.class)
public List<T> getAll(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    return getAll(uriInfo.getQueryParameters());
}
```

And have that serialized under the view `JSONEntity`. Is this possible with RestEasy? If not, how can I emulate that?

**Edit:** I know I can do the serialization myself:

```
public String getAll(@Context UriInfo info, @Context Providers factory) {
    List<T> entities = getAll(info.getQueryParameters());
    ObjectMapper mapper = factory.getContextResolver(
         ObjectMapper.class, MediaType.APPLICATION
    ).getContext(entityClass);
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(entities);
}
```

However, this is clumsy at best and defeats the whole idea of having the *framework* deal with this boilerplate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, it *is* possible to simply annotate a specific endpoint with `@JsonView` (just as in my question) and jackson will use this view. Who would have guessed.

You can even do this in the generic way ([more context in my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253114/when-overriding-jacksonjsonprovider-writeto-can-i-specify-the-view-used-to-seri)), but that ties me to RestEasy:

```
@Override
public void writeTo(Object value, Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
        Annotation[] annotations,  MediaType mediaType, 
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHd, 
        OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    Class view = getViewFromType(type, genericType);
    ObjectMapper mapper = locateMapper(type, mediaType);

    Annotation[] myAnn = Arrays.copyOf(annotations, annotations.length + 1);
    myAnn[annotations.length] = new JsonViewQualifier(view);

    super.writeTo(value, type, genericType, myAnn, mediaType, httpHd, out);
}

private Class getViewFromType(Class<?> type, Type genericType) {
    // unwrap collections
    Class target = org.jboss.resteasy.util.Types.getCollectionBaseType(
            type, genericType);
    target = target != null ? target : type;
    try {
        // use my mix-in as view class
        return Class.forName("example.jackson.JSON" + target.getSimpleName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.info("No view found for {}", target.getSimpleName());
    }
    return Object.class;
}
```