# When overriding JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo, can I specify the view used to serialize?

Tags: java, annotations, jackson

I have a setup with Resteasy-3.0.6, Jackson-2.2.3 and CDI (running on Wildfly-8.0.0.CR1). In my case, every entity has a mix-in class that extends it and specifies the attributes that are to be serialized. There are two "views", let's call them *Basic* and *Extended*. Since what kind of view of an object I need depends on the "root" object of the serialization, these views need to be per object. So I re-use the mix-in classes for that. Example:

```
public class Job { 
    @Id private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="job") private Set<Bonus> bonuses;
}

public class Bonus {
    @Id private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(optional=false) private Job job;
    private BigDecimal value;
}

public abstract class JsonJob extends Job { 
    abstract Long getId();

    @JsonView({ JsonJob.class })
    abstract Set<Bonus> getBonuses();
}

public abstract class JsonBonus extends Bonus {
    abstract BigDecimal getValue();
}
```

Now I'm looking for a way to hook into jackson's serialization process to specify `JsonJob` as a view iff the root entity is `Job`. I'm currently using `JacksonJsonProvider#writeTo`:

```
@Override
public void writeTo(Object value, Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
                    Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, 
                    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, 
                    OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException {
    Class view = getViewForType(type); // if no mix-in class is set, return Object
    ObjectMapper mapper = locateMapper(type, mediaType);

    // require all properties to be explicitly specified for serialization
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
    mapper.registerModule(new SerializationMixinConf()); // registers all mix-ins

    super.writeTo(value, type, genericType, annotations, mediaType, 
        httpHeaders, entityStream);
}
```

The point is: this works, *iff* the calling method is annotated `@JsonView`. **But** since the main user of this is a generic super-class, I can't add the annotation to the method directly. Can someone suggest a way to either set the view in the existing mapper (`setSerializationConfig()` seems to be gone in jackson-2) or dynamically add the `@JsonView` to the `annotations` array?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have in `writeTo` now:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = locateMapper(type, mediaType);
// require all properties to be explicitly specified for serialization
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
mapper.registerModule(new SerializationMixinConf());

// TODO: check if we already have @JsonView
Annotation[] myAnnotations = Arrays.copyOf(annotations, annotations.length + 1);
myAnnotations[annotations.length] = new JsonViewQualifier(view);

super.writeTo(value, type, genericType, myAnnotations, mediaType, 
    httpHeaders, entityStream);
```

And the qualifier simply extends from [AnnotationLiteral](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.html):

```
public class JsonViewQualifier extends AnnotationLiteral<JsonView> 
        implements JsonView {
    private final Class[] views;

    public JsonViewQualifier(Class[] views) { this.views = views; }
    public JsonViewQualifier(Class view) { this(new Class[] { view }); }

    @Override
    public Class<?>[] value() {
        return views;
    }
}
```

Note that this will generate a *new* writer for each view (as it should).

Answer (score 0):

With Jackson 2.3, you can use `@JsonView` on JAX-RS end points, if that would help.

But if not, another possibility is to use `ObjectWriter` directly (writers are created from `ObjectMapper`), constructing writer with specific view. This is fully dynamic and can be done on per-call basis. This requires sort of by-passing JAX-RS logic and usually you will need to return `StreamingOutput` (instead of actual POJO), but it is the ultimate in configurability.

Comment: Is the "calling method" (the one annotated with `@GET`) the same as the "JAX-RS end point"? If so, do have a idea why it works with the jackson-jaxrs-2.2.3 bundled with wildfly-8.0.0.CR1?