# Alter a Jackson mapped JSON object only for the response

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

I have a class that I use for things that I pull from Kafka or store in Redis.  However, I just want to remove a couple of sensitive entries from it before I send it to the user.

One approach I had was to create a separate return class and copy each field one at a time, but I switched to a different approach in that I use object mapper to convert it to a map and then just strip off the element.

However, I was wondering if there was a nicer way.

I can't use @JsonIgnore as I am using it with @JsonProperty right now.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279782/what-is-the-json-view-class-in-jackson-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: almost, I use RESTEasy though so I can't use the RestController.  I am adding JAX-RS to the tags

Comment: How about this (RESTEasy-specific)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634275/can-i-specify-the-jackson-jsonview-to-use-for-method-result-transformation-in-r